# How to change stdin in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like assign a file to `sys.stdin` so that I can read contents of the file with `input()`. The code below runs as expected as script but it is problematic when it is written in notebook. After calling function `input()` it shows me an input textbook, which I do not want since I reassigned stdin to a file. So, I expect that the line in the file would be read instead.

```
import sys
file = open("input.in")
sys.stdin = file
val = input()
print(val)
```

It seems to me notebook ignores `sys.stdin`. I couldn't find why this is happening and how to fix it.

Thanks.

**Update**

I end up with overriding `input` function. It will do the job but I leave question open to see if someone has a better solution.

```
file = open("input.in")
input = file.readline
```

Answer (score 3):

You can read the file to an in-memory buffer and then direct stdin to read from that. For example, to redisplay a file

```
import sys
import io      # in python2, import StringIO

input_file = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
sys.stdin = io.StringIO(input_file.read())

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line, end='')
```

For your purpose, you may want

```
import sys
import io      # in python2, import StringIO

input_file = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
sys.stdin = io.StringIO(input_file.read())

val = sys.stdin.readline()
# Rest of program using val
```

Comment: Thanks for response but I should read the file with `input()` function. I think, I can just `input=file.readline` or `input=fileio.readline` where `fileio` is `StringIO` object. I don't accept the answer to see whether someone else will offer a better solution or an explanation about why `input()` does not read from `sys.stdin`.

Comment: I'm trying to mock `stdin` for `Jupyter Notebook`. I've many `shell` command cells, e.g. `!aws configure` that require stdin. Do I place `val = sys.stdin.readline()` in a separate cell before or after the `shell` command cell? or Do I place `val = ...`, in the same cell but a line before or after the `shell` command line? @davidlowryduda @Seljuk Gülcan