# Interact with the shell and enter stdin values in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, shell, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, stdin

I am using `AWS SagerMaker` `JupyterLab`.

I want to be able to interact with the `shell` and enter `stdin` values.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069402/how-to-change-stdin-in-jupyter-notebook) explains that you can, but I am unsure how to implement it.

The linked post suggests: `val = sys.stdin.readline()`, but I have been placing copies of it everywhere with no luck.

**What would be a de-facto standard approach?** I need to apply this for other `stdin` processes throughput my Notebook.

---

So far, I have...

Code:

```
import sys
import io

input_file = open('stdinputs.txt', 'r')
sys.stdin = io.StringIO(input_file.read())
```

Cell (requesting `stdin`):

```
!tensorboard dev upload --logdir tb_logs --name "OntologyTagger" --description "OntologyTagger" --one_shot
```

`stdinputs.txt`:

```
yes
```

---

Note: This screenshot was taken in `Google Colab`, where you can enter straight into shell. I require `AWS SageMaker` `JupyterLab` for hardware acceleration, which unfortunately doesn't have such a feature.
[image: screenshot of cell requesting stdin]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing `yes` as an argument as well?

```
!tensorboard dev upload --logdir tb_logs --name "OntologyTagger" --description "OntologyTagger" --one_shot --yes
```